# C++ Function Returning Pointer to Dynamically Allocated Object

Tags: c++

I have two Class A and B.

```
class B
{
};

class A
{
   public:
        B* CreateB( void )
        {
            B* obj = new B();
            return obj;
        }
}
```

When the client calls A::CreateB(), it has to delete the returned B* pointer even it does not know the underlying implementation. Is there any way to avoid this? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<B> CreateB() { return std::unique_ptr<B>(new B()); }`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use Constructor and Destructor, the following code:
But, this method is not recommended! You should read the book -- `effective c++`

```
class B
{
};

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        obj = new B();
    }

    ~A()
    {
        if (obj)
        {
            delete obj;
        }
    }
   B* obj;
};
```

second, you should use smart pointer, the following code:

```
class B
{
};

class A
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<B> CrteateB( void )
    {
        std::shared_ptr<B> obj(new B);
        return obj;
    }
};
```

Comment: Class A and B are not of composition or aggregation relation in my case. The client can call A::CreateB() to obtain different instances of Class B. So the first approach seems not fit.

Comment: Is there any way that the client prepares Class B instance on the stack, and which is also returned from A::CreateB()?

Comment: why use `A::CreateB()`? I think you shoud use `A.CreateB()` or `A->CreateB()`.

Comment: Yes, A::CreateB() means the client calls the function CreateB() of Class A. It does not mean CreateB() is static function of Class A.